# Searchable recycler view containing radio group in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, radio-button, radio-group

Each item of my recycler view contains a text view and a radio group. The radio group contains 3 radio buttons.

Now I need this recycler view to be searchable. I have a edit text view from which I'm getting the input string for search and then I'm updating the list of items of the recycler view based on that string.

Now the problem is that after filtering and a selecting a radio button when the filter is cleared, the selection gets messed up.

I tried clearing the selection and then resetting it manually but still it is not working.

Could you please describe how should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a property to the model from which you created the list. That property holds the selected RadioButton index.
You also need to create two lists, one for storing values (Main list) and the other for display (the list passed to the adapter). Then change the values in the main list after each change in the display list